# How to force close javascript in an app wrapped by nativefier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I have a web app that is wrapped by Nativefier (https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier). 
Nativefier uses electron for achieving this.
My app has a javascript file, say app.js and during a specific circumstance, my app closes itself by -

```
var win = window.open("","_self");
win.close();
```

The opened tab or window is closed in Google Chrome. But in nativefier, it is not functioning.
So how do I close this native app window from within my app.js

Comment: Not entirely sure (I am new to Electron), but I think that the window would need to be created as a `BrowserWindow`. I could be completely wrong, though...

Comment: Yes true, but in the way i see it,  nativefier does not have any api for the same! I went through the code and I could not find any hook for browser window close.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to open a popup window and then close it, or simply close the app itself using your JS file?